# original_exception method stops working on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Upgrading from Rails 4 to Rails 5, the following code, in an exception handler, stops working:

```
exception.instance_of?(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) && exception.original_exception.is_a?(PG::Error)
```

which now gives this error:

```
<NoMethodError: undefined method `original_exception' for #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:0x00007fd2ceb4ba10>>
```

Based on this [post](https://travisofthenorth.com/blog/2016/10/15/postgres-rails-sandbox), I am trying to do this in the Pry exception handler, so the full code is:

```
Pry.config.exception_handler = proc do |output, exception, _pry_|
  output.puts "#{exception.class}: #{exception.message}"
  output.puts exception.backtrace.first

  if exception.instance_of?(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) && exception.original_exception.is_a?(PG::Error)
    output.puts 'Rolling back transaction and starting a new one!'
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    connection.rollback_db_transaction
    connection.begin_db_transaction
  end
end
```

This code allows the `rails console` to recover from an ActiveRecord exception. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not just `rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, PG::Error`?

Comment: @max, I have added more information. I tried changing the if condition to ```exception.instance_of?(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, PG::Error)``` but that threw an error.